# android: how to import zip file into raw file and make it recognizable?

Tags: android, zip

I want to import a zip file (test.zip, < 1m) into android's `res\raw` folder and I am using *Eclipse -> import*.

After I imported the zip file, I used it as `Resources.openRawResource(R.raw.test);` however there was always an error that said: `test can not be resolved or is not a field`...

I am so confused, I am not sure why this happened. please help, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

i may know the reason after a long research, it may be because this test.zip file has sub folders in it. for res/raw, it doesn't support sub folders. if you have better answer or you think mine is not correct, please let me know, thanks!